# Yii renderPartial only some form fields

Tags: yii, renderpartial

I need to include a view (_form) that shows only certain fields.

```
$user = new User;
$this->renderPartial('//User/_form', array('model'=>$user));
```

In this function, you can specify which fields to show?

Thanks

Comment: What is the code of your view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can show what folder it is, like for example in views/user/_form :

```
$this->renderPartial('application.views.user._form', array('model'=>$user));
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#renderPartial-detail

UPDATE:
you can send renderPartial a variable and check for that variable with your logic, in _form.php

in form.php

```
$this->renderPartial('application.views.user._form',
     array('model'=>$user , 'condition'=>$condition));
```

in your _form.php

```
if($conition == 'check for something') // show the field, or Not!
{
    echo $form->textField($user, 'username');
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but i'm not explaining correctly. I want to display only some field inside _form partial. For example: in _form I have username, password and name field. I want to display only username and password field. It's possible to passing in "RenderPartial" only some field?

Answer (score 0):

`renderPartial` only renders the provided view file (without including layout), so if you want to include only some of the form fields you will have to pass some variable (like an array) which will output the parts of a code using `if` statement (or similar idea).

In short the answer to your question will be: NO. `renderPartial` works like `render` the difference is that it renders the view file without including layout file.